# Hover effect on table row

Tags: css, hover

I have a table with a class applied and I want to add a hover effect to all rows with a specific class name. But this doesn't seem to work. Using chrome. Must work in IE8 as well. Can anyone help me get this working please?

html ->

```
<table class="myTable">
<tr class="myRow">
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

css ->

```
.myTable.myRow tr:hover td{
 background-color:red;
```

}

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sophie/th5tawt8/)

Comment: This is because your table doesnt also have a class of `.myRow` try this: `.myTable tr.myRow:hover td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have applied the class slightly wrong change it to:

```
.myTable tr.myRow:hover td{
     background-color:red;   
}
```

Reasoning being in your css you are saying find the class `myTable` that also has class `myRow` but its your `tr` element with the `myRow` class.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use this:

```
.myRow:hover {
    background:red;   
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/th5tawt8/5/)